# How to slow down animation time in Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I was trying to slow down the animation in recharts but i did not get any idea about it ..

I have tried in CSS part but that does not work

**isAnimationActive={true}** is to enable animation 
**isAnimationActive={false}** is to disable animation 
is there anyway to handle animation time ,

This is my Code

```
const {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];
const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis yAxisId="left" />
       <YAxis yAxisId="right" orientation="right" />
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line yAxisId="left" type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Line yAxisId="right" type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[recharts Js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tmw6q51h/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=tmw6q51h)

Comment: `animationDuration` is what you need here.

Comment: Thanks . Tan ...

Answer (score 5):

**the Soution is**

```
let duration = 1000; 
animationDuration={duration}
```